# Google cloud load balancing instance status

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've tried few different setups of `HTTP load balancing` in google compute engine.

I used this as a reference :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example

And I'm at scenario with 3 instances where I simulate the outage on one of them.
[image]

And I can see that one instance is not healthy which is great, so my question would be how can I see which one of them is not up. I mean when this is a real scenario I want to immediately know which one is it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the gcloud tool to get detailed health information. Based on that tutorial, I would run:

```
gcloud compute backend-services get-health NAME
```

I am not sure how to view this information in the developer console.

See more:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#health_checking